# 2007 templates broken in 2013

Tags: 2007, 2013, upgrade, visual-web-part, template

We're upgrading to SP2013 from 2007 and using 2010 as a stepping stone for the DB upgrade.
(This is all out of production, we're building a plan to do production)
The problem we're having is that many of our (My understanding is default) templates are broken or use web parts that aren't installed

The big one is the Knowledge Base template.  I can't seem to find one compatible with SP15 ANYWHERE.  I've tried the one out of the "Fab 40" to no avail.

I'm not as familiar with Sharepoint as I would really like to be.

I've backed up the WSS_Content DB and restored it to a new SQL instance and ran the schema upgrade to 2010 and then to 2013 and that's where I sit right now.

I'm convinced it's just some small thing I'm missing?

These also show up as pieces preventing the visual upgrade to 2013

Answer (score 1):

The Fab 40 templates weren't so fabulous and caused a lot of headaches so they were discontinued.  While these were available from Microsoft, these were not base product and did not come with that level of support.  They are installed via solution packages, and these packages were not compatible in most cases in 2010 so the upgrade from 2007 to 2010 may not complete successfully.

You are going to need to move away from those sites and re-do the upgrade.

Comment: What method would you recommend? Are we talking just opening the template in Designer and tweaking orrr?  I don't know if we actually used the KB template from the Fab 40 in the original setup, I just downloaded it and installed it in hopes that it would fix our issue.

Comment: On the 2007 farm you will need to deactivate and fully remove those solutions from the farm and remove any sites that reference it.  Then you can bring the content database to the 2010 farm and run the upgrade process, followed by the upgrade to the 2013 farm.

Comment: Also, you should always run the test-spcontentdatabase powershell command before attaching any database to 2010 or 2013.  This will alert you to any problems such as missing dependencies before it part of your farm.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607941.aspx