# Migrating a 'FAB40' call centre site from 2007 to 2013

Tags: 2013, migration, fab-40

I am trying to migrate a site that was created using the FAB40 Call center template from Sharepoint 2007 to 2013. After installing the 2007 site template in 2013 using compatibility level {14,15} I am able to see all the content.

The problem is this picture that keeps popping up all over the site.
[image]

How do I remove this image from the site? I found that this image is named spcommon.png. Is this because of some wrong reference in the site template? How do I change this or even remove it?

Comment: How are you going from 2007 straight to 2013? Using a product like Metalogix or something? I'm pretty sure the fab 40 solutions weren't compatible with 2010 so they are almost certainly not compatible with 2013.

Comment: @pigeon We are simply going from 2007 -> 2010 ->2013 via the backup and upgrade path. The templates worked fine when moved from 2007 -> 2010. Its on 2013 that I am getting the  problem.

Comment: Might want to look at this one> http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66201/2007-templates-broken-in-2013/66202#66202

Comment: spcommon.png if you closely look having the small icons in sharepoint.....you that is drawbacks and you also be ready for these kind of risks when you trying to use the something which is not compatibile....did you try to use the sharepoint designer and open the page and remove it? Also did your site upgraded to SharePoint 2013 complete or still in 2010 mode....http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/03/24/deploy-sharepoint-2010-solutions-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE the site ui also has been upgraded to 2013. There was an error when i tried opening the site in SP Designer. Thanks for the link..will haev a look.